# mysql : unable to create secondary server instance using mysqld

Tags: mysql

I am using mysqld to create an new server along with the existing one[ MYSQL 8.0.27 installed with the windows installer] to test data replication

I already have an instance of the server installed [called Mysql80] which is the original server and i am trying to create another server called MyTest using mysqld by reading [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-windows-command-line-servers.html) documentation which seems simple enough

i have created an empty Data directory to hold my new database and my configuration file for the server is saved as conf.cnf

```
[MyTest]
port = 3310
datadir = E:/Program Files/Developer/MYSQL/Data/TestFolder/Data
```

from the windows command line i create the server using their exact instructions

```
mysqld  --defaults-file=E:/conf.cnf  --console
```

--console is used to display debugging information but i always get these error's

```
021-12-12T17:17:11.844725Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 2328
2021-12-12T17:17:11.875406Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-12-12T17:17:13.498780Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2021-12-12T17:17:13.866706Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2021-12-12T17:17:13.867207Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.867617Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.868042Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.868519Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.868926Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.869354Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.869707Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-12-12T17:17:13.979431Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-12-12T17:17:14.140027Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-12-12T17:17:14.172455Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-12-12T17:17:14.172592Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-12-12T17:17:14.175122Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-12-12T17:17:14.175319Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-12-12T17:17:14.176633Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/netwo k address/port) is normally permitted.
2021-12-12T17:17:14.176755Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-12-12T17:17:14.177195Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-12-12T17:17:15.446688Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Ignoring the optimizer error's and cannot find table error's the server always tries to start on port 3306 even though i have specified in my conf file it should be on port 3310

Which makes me believe that i typed the config file in the wrong format or i haven't specified enough parameters for the job

any ideas?

Comment: Just use a VM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out i was doing two things wrong

1. I had previously upgraded from mysql 8 to 8.27 hence tables were corrupted which explained the Optimization errors
2. My config wasn't in the correct format

After deleting the MySQL service from windows services and deleting my data directory these 3 steps need to be performed in order

1. Create an new directory to store Data, your config file , upload directory[To Use commands like LOAD FILE]

The structure looks like this

```
->Warehouse1
 |--->Data
 |--->Uploads
 |--->MyConfig.cnf
```

Where MyConfig.cnf looks as follows

```
[mysqld]
basedir="E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Server 8.0"
port=3306
datadir="E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Storage\WareHouse1\Data"
secure-file-priv="E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Storage\WareHouse1\Uploads"
```

2)Initialize the data directory from your windows command line using mysqld as follows

```
mysqld --defaults-file="E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Storage\WareHouse1\config.cnf" --initialize
```

3)Finally create an service which you can change in Windows Services window

```
mysqld --install MySQL81  --defaults-file="E:\Program Files\Developer\MYSQL\Storage\WareHouse1\config.cnf"
```

Repeat the same steps to create an second server.